# Android Java Alignment issues

Tags: java, android

So, on different devices my the images are centered
this is what is should look like.

Pretty much i cant get the things to be centered

[image]

And this is what is looks like on the emulator

[image]

```css
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/square"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
       android:src="@drawable/square" ></ImageView>
       
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/title"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/lol" ></ImageView>
   
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/bruh"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:src="@drawable/button" ></ImageView>
   
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/bruhText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
      android:textSize="17dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="Bruh" />

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/twenty"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
       android:src="@drawable/button" ></ImageView>
    
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/twentyText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="166dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
      android:textSize="17dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="21" />
     
  <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/stoopid"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
       android:src="@drawable/button" ></ImageView>

 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/stoopidText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="166dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="195dp"
      android:textSize="17dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="Stoopid" />
 
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/ornah"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:src="@drawable/button" ></ImageView>
    
      <TextView
      android:id="@+id/ornahText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
      android:textSize="17dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="Or Nah" />
    
     <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/burger"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
       android:src="@drawable/button" ></ImageView>
     
     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/burgerText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="116dp"
      android:textSize="17dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="Burger" />
     
     <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/noinot"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
       android:src="@drawable/button" ></ImageView>
     
     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/noinotText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="195dp"
      android:textSize="17dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="No I Not" />
    
    
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/smackcam"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:src="@drawable/button" ></ImageView>
    
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/smackcamText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="325dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
      android:textSize="15dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="Smack Cam" />
    
     <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/backflip"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
       android:src="@drawable/button" ></ImageView>
     
          <TextView
      android:id="@+id/backflipText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="325dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="112dp"
      android:textSize="15dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="BackFlip" />
     
     <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/pop"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
       android:src="@drawable/button" ></ImageView>
     
     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/popText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="325dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
      android:textSize="17dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="P.O.P" />
```

Comment: Without looking at the code, you need to set the layout_gravity to be centered

Comment: On all of them? @AlexK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you've gone in and made everything static.

You defined the location of every single textbox by pixel, and that's not the way to do it.

You need to create a horizontal `LinearLayout`, populate it with 3 vertical `LinearLayout`s that hold the pictures, then set `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` for the horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Consider figuring out how to group this stuff more.

Another option is to use a grid. Or a `TableLayout` with `TableRow`s.

This process is how you make things scalable to different devices, which is the whole point and advantage of Android.

I hope that helped. Good luck :)

Comment: Sure. Here is a tutorial on using layouts inside of layouts: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Exploring-Android-Linearlayout-And-Relativelayout/ Just google "how to use relativelayout inside linearlayout" and a ton of things come up

Comment: If you're still confused tomorrow morning, just reply to me as a comment here and I can write some example code for you.